# "Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated" YET Play Console says "Your app doesn't require sensitive permissions"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-permissions, google-play-console

After uploading my first Flutter release app bundle I get this error:

> Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated.

and other answers say to "fill out declaration of location permission."  I couldn't find it, so I searched for "permissions declaration" on Google Play Console and THAT screen tells me this:

> Your app doesn't request sensitive permissions, so you don't need to
> do anything here

***Obviously something is not being set/configured or something is inconsistent.***

These are my permissions:

Required permissions (7)
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Comment: No.  Thanks... just above.  I removed ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION and it fixed it for now, but what if I want that permission in the future?

Comment: Whoops I totally misread that last night. Yeah that seems like a bug in the console. I'd bet that next time if you do require that, it'll show up properly. If not then I guess it'd be a support ticket with google?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hywRv.png)

Its on bottom of left bar, in App Content / Sensitive Permission adn APIs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33005388)